# Finding a professor beforehand

Tags: professorship, advisor

I want to know your opinion about the following situation.

Having read all recommendations on how to apply to graduate school abroad, how to choose the professor to work with, I found a really interesting suggestion of someone. The person was describing the similar process applying to graduate school and in parallel he was looking for someone to work with in the same university, a bit early but if know what do you want to do, why not to do it. Having found a good candidate to work with, the person offered to work together for from few weeks to few months.

This person was lucky, he made a really good choice, they decided to proceed working together towards a masters degree and application to the university was a useless formality.

One minor point though, it was a quite expensive, to buy a fly ticket, rent a room etc.

What is your opinion about this form of finding a professor, do you have more examples like this?

Comment: Contacting potential supervisors before applying for Graduate School is a must. If you can't afford or haven't got time to travel, then perhaps try arranging a Skype meeting with them.

Comment: Whether it's a must depends on the sort of department and how they run admissions.  For example, in my department students are admitted by a committee, and I wouldn't want to try to pull strings to get someone admitted based on a Skype call or personal meeting if their application didn't look compelling to the committee (if I even could, which is doubtful).  And a large fraction of the applicants are rejected anyway, so it wouldn't be efficient to have the in-person discussions before the admissions decision.

Comment: Fair enough perhaps it's not a must in all fields but I don't see how it could hurt.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it would secure a place either, just that it could help you decide if that academic is someone you'd be interested in working with

Comment: @LisaG: You must meet with an advisor before joining the group. It's not necessarily a must to do so before applying! (Particularly in the case Anonymous Mathematician describes—which also applies in my field.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to find a good professor to work with, you could search for the available professors in a certain university (online, in their website).

After having all the names, you could "stalk" them online, find some of their papers, etc. Most of them (if not all) will have a webpage in which they post lots of information about themselves, such as, their papers, students they worked with, even their hobbies. You'll probably delete quite a few names that way.

You'll still have some professors names not crossed out. You can then try to e-mail the students they worked with and ask them what's their evaluation of said professor.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, sorry if it's not.

Comment: thank you for the answer, according to my experience, the best way to understand whether you are capable to work with professor or not is actually to get to know him personally, talk to him, maybe start to work with him, the second good option, is to take courses he teaches, within three or four lectures you will be sure. By asking students I never received a negative evaluation, however half of them were unhappy with professor, which I learned afterward occasionally. Personal webpages might be very misleading.

Comment: I agree with your comment user10756. However, I still feel it's a good way to cross out some names. Also, I understood from your post that you wanted non expensives ways. Attending a few lectures abroad would be quite expensive, imho. You could try to search for online lectures. In comes down to this: If don't want to spend any money, that is, you don't want to travell aboard to have a meeting with a professor, than your only chance of getting to know, not fully know, but having some clue, of/your professor, than it is by searching him online, or asking people who know him.